# Plotting a list of arrays as an animation (against a fixed x axis) in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plotly, matplotlib-animation

I have a dataset that is of shape (n, x, 2). The length of x is fixed, such as 5. So for each n, I have an array of size (x, 2). For each n, I want to plot the first column of (x, 2) against x as an animation. I've tried doing this:

```
def spatial_animation(data):
    """
    Args:
        data: [n, n_x, 2] 
    """

    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    x = data.shape[1]

    x = np.linspace(0, 1, x) # fixed array of size x 
    y = np.array([y[:, 0] for y in data])

    fig = plt.figure()
    graph, = plt.plot([], [])

    def animate(i):
        graph.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])
        return graph

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=30, interval=200)
    plt.show()
```

This ends up giving something strange, and the animation also "flickers." Is there a standard way to plot this time of thing, such as via either matplotlib.animation or plotly express?

Update: Assume data is an (n, x, 2) array, such as:

```
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=((200, 5, 2))
```

Now, call `spatial_animation(data)` to get the plot: this doesn't really give a plot.

Comment: It is better to give working example.

Comment: I've updated to give an example of what the "data" array that you feed into "spatial_animation" would look like. I don't know how to embed the output "animated" figure but everything is there to reproduce things now.

Comment: To add to this, the output figure is usually just a blank GUI.